# How to get traffic sources of my visitors?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

What is the best way to get information about traffic sources of visitors on my web application? I want to store that information in database after every created an account by user.

I know that is possibility to get that information from google analytics cookies (utm*). But some browser extensions like adblock are blocking these cookies.

Comment: `information about visitors`  Could you elaborate?  Do you mean demographic profile?

Comment: Just only traffic sources

Answer (score 2):

If by traffic source you mean: were where the user before landing into your web site, you could capture the document.referrer value.

Answer (score 1):

you may get visitor IP-Address for unique visitor.
Which technology you are used?
If you are used PHP Technology.Here is the code for find IP

```
echo SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score -1):

main point is which types of traffic you want? means organic, social or referral traffics.

there are many ways to get traffics:
 - if your site is new, best option is paid marketing like PPC, PR etc.
 - your site is old then guest posting with high DA is best option. apart from social media traffics is also good option. now a days you can also get targeted social media traffics with Facebook paid marketing.

here are some of google links which you will get good tips

- http://neilpatel.com/2016/03/22/how-to-increase-website-traffic-without-seo/
- http://www.thecrazythinkers.com/11-killer-tips-increase-traffic-website-blog/

if you will get specific need, i will guide you with exact answer.